# Get monthly data from timestamp and sort by the same month

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I tried to show table by monthly total duration, so I did sort by duration of same monthly data of timestamp, but I couldn't.

My goal is to create a table by return value that an object or array value.

```
public function monthlyResult(Request $request = null)
{
  $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

         if($request){
            $year = $request->year;
            $month = $request->month;
         }
         else{
            $year = date('Y');
         }


         $monthlyResult = DB::table('workings')
        ->where('user_id', $user_id)
        ->whereYear('created_at', $year)
        ->orwhere(function ($query) use($user_id, $year) {
            $query->where('user_id', $user_id)
            ->whereYear('deleted_at', $year);
        })
        ->get();

        foreach($monthlyResult as $mResult){
          $month = date('n', strtotime($mResult->created_at));
          $duration = $mResult->duration;

        ---- code ----
        }
   return ;
}
```

month  |   total duration |

----1---  |      xxxxxxxx      |

----2---  |      xxxxxxxx      |

----3---  |      xxxxxxxx      |

...

---11---  |      xxxxxxxx      |

---12---  |      xxxxxxxx      |

Comment: did you try `order_by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an associate array and sort by key

```
$results = [];

foreach($monthlyResult as $mResult){
   $month = date('n', strtotime($mResult->created_at));
   $results[$month] = (isset($results[$month])) ? ($results[$month] + $mResult->duration) : $mResult->duration ;
}

//now sort $results based on key
ksort($results);
```

As mention by @C2486 you can directly sort your record using `orderBy`

```
$monthlyResult = DB::table('workings')
        ->where('user_id', $user_id)
        ->whereYear('created_at', $year)
        ->orwhere(function ($query) use ($user_id, $year) {
            $query->where('user_id', $user_id)
            ->whereYear('deleted_at', $year);
        })
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('month(created_at)'))
        ->get();
```

Comment: `dd($results);` result is 
`array:8 [▼
  `1` => 633600.0
  `2` => 576000.0
  `3` => 574800.0
  `4` => 576000.0
  `5` => 547200.0
  `6` => 604800.0
  `7` => 604800.0
  `8` => 633600.0
]`

Comment: did you apply `ksort($results);` ?

Comment: check modified comment,

Comment: didn't you want that ?

Comment: My record have ten records and two records is same month(2, 6). So I expect to add into there duration, but replaced with last duration to month(2 and 6) when through `foreach roop`. :(

Comment: Is there have any solution as `array_values($results[$month], $mResult->duration);` ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177995/discussion-between-rkj-and-magnetic).